# Undo a reopen request?

Tags: support, vote-to-reopen

A question I had answered was closed as duplicate. I originally thought this was incorrect, and voted to reopen the question. However, the guy who closed the question explained his rationale for doing so and he is competely correct. Is there a way for me to undo my reopen vote?

Comment: It's only going to matter if it gets 5 reopen votes.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not currently possible to retract a reopen vote.

However, your reopen vote will have bumped the question into the Reopen Votes queue. If reviewers choose to leave it closed, the aging process will begin immediately and your reopen vote will automatically expire after four days assuming no other reopen votes get cast.