# Please allow us to rescind reopen votes

Tags: support, feature-request, vote-to-reopen

It is currently not possible to undo a reopen vote:

- [Undo a reopen request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284239/undo-a-reopen-request)

Please add a feature to allow us to do so, in the same way that we can undo a close vote.

Previous questions asked "can we?" I am asking for the answer to that to be "yes!" It will help us to keep the site tidy and reduce the "Reopen votes" review queue.

Comment: You can't revoke a delete vote either; that would be nice for the *rare* occasions a users actually puts the effort into fix the (mess of a) question/answer.

Comment: @Larnu There isn't a delete votes review queue, unless you include the review queues tools, so we can't use the review queue angle to add weight to the request. However, if I saw a question asking for that feature, I'm sure I'd upvote it ;)

Comment: Never been burned on a re-open, but there have been a few times I've voted to delete only for the asker to fix the question.  One time I was able to prevent deletion by upvoting the revised question to a -2, but others were nuked with my name regretfully attached even though they had become reasonable questions. Worse, I couldn't find them again to raise a mod flag.

Comment: @user4581301 You have 10k+ rep, so you can see deleted posts. That means you should be able to find [the delete vote you cast in your history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4581301/user4581301?tab=votes&sort=deletion), click through to the post, and raise a mod flag on it. (Not saying this is an ideal workflow, but it does exist.) (Also note: I *cannot* see that page in your profile, even though I'm a mod. The "Votes" tab is private. I generated that URL based on what I can see for my own profile on a site where I'm not a mod.)

Comment: @CodyGray Thank you very much. That'll help out next time.